# Assign a value to an input using jquery.

Tags: jquery

So simple and embarrassing!

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="sliderValue" data-index="0" value="33"/>
```

JS:

```
$('#sliderValue').val("New val");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vj2y6/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work because you did not include jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#sliderValue').val('New Val');
});
```

Actually `ready` is a `jQuery` event, which tells the browser that, once the `Dom` is ready then execute the function that has been passed in the `ready` event. [Check here for more](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/vj2y6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your code after the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#sliderValue').val("New val");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should select some version of jQuery in the Framework & Extension section to use it in jsfiddle.